# Creating a kubernetes cluster on GCP using Spinnaker

Tags: spinnaker

For end to end devops automation I want to have an environment on demand. For this I need to Spun up and environment on kubernetes which is eventually hosted on GCP.
My Use case 
1. Developer Checks in the code in feature branch 
2. Environment in Spun up on Google Cloud with Kubernetes
3. Application gets deployed on Kubernetes
4. Gets tested and then the environment gets destroyed.

I am able to do everything with Spinnaker except #2. i.e  create Kube Cluster on GCP using Spinnaker. 
Any help please

Thanks,
Amol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure Spinnaker was meant for doing what the second point in your list. Spinnaker assumes a collection of resources (VM's or a Kubernetes cluster) and then works with that. So instead of spinning up a new GKE cluster Spinnaker makes use of existing clusters. I think it'd be better (for you costs as well ;) if you seperate the environments using Kubernetes namespaces.